# Apache Rewrite rule to add namespace to URL if not present

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am pretty new to Apache.

Consider I have URL like http://www.abc.com/home

I want this URL to be redirected to http://www.abc.com/foo/home.

Basically, I want to add "**foo/**" to URL if not present. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/foo       [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)     /foo/home/$1 [L,NC]
```

For permanent redirection, replace [L,NC] with [R=301,L,NC]